# fill missing dates for specific key and value

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
array (size=3)
  0 =>
    array (size=3)
      'quantity' => string '20' (length=2)
      'date' => string '2016-01-01' (length=10)
      'eID' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 =>
    array (size=3)
      'quantity' => string '10' (length=2)
      'date' => string '2016-03-01' (length=10)
      'eID' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 =>
    array (size=3)
      'quantity' => string '15' (length=2)
      'date' => string '2016-01-01' (length=10)
      'eID' => string '1' (length=1)
```

how can i fill missing date for each 'eID'? so the output would be:

```
array (
   0 =>
     array (
       'quantity' => string '20' (length=2)
       'date' => string '2016-01-01' (length=10)
       'eID' => string '2' (length=1)
   1 =>
     array (
       'quantity' => null
       'date' => string '2016-02-01' (length=10)
       'eID' => string '2' (length=1)
   2 =>
     array (
       'quantity' => string '10' (length=2)
       'date' => string '2016-03-01' (length=10)
       'eID' => string '2' (length=1)
```

...until 2016-12-01. 12 arrays for each 'eID' key with same value

Comment: writing code would be a good start. We don't do that for you. you write code, we (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: As Mark said, at least try and get back here and update your question :)

Comment: why `eID` should be reindexed in the result?

Comment: Here are some tips to get you started: First sort the array usort() and converting the dates to timestamps (strtotime()) in the the user defined sorting function. Then take the first date in the array, convert it to timestamp, start a loop and add 24*3600 seconds to the time in each iteration, for as long as the time < 2016-12-01, looking at the source array if it already exists and saving the data in a new output array (using the original array will probably distort your output). Good luck!